# Verifying NSEC3 records

Tags: hash, dns, dnssec

I'm fiddling with DNSSEC, and I'd like to try to verify NSEC3 records generated by `dnssec-signzone` from `bind9-utils` (which I presume are valid). This is my zone file:

```
$ORIGIN dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.
$TTL 120
@   SOA dnssectestns.mvolfik.tk. email.example.com. 15 259200 3600 300000 3600
    A   192.168.0.101
s3c A   192.168.0.101

$INCLUDE zsk.key
$INCLUDE ksk.key
```

ZSK and KSK are generated with `dnssec-keygen -a ECDSAP256SHA256 dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.` (add `-f KSK` respectively)

I then signed it using the command `dnssec-signzone -3 deadbeef -H 5 -o dnssectest.mvolfik.tk -k ksk.key zonefile zsk.key` (use NSEC3 with `deadbeef` hex salt, 5 iterations)

I got the following NSEC3 records in the `zonefile.signed`: (omitted RRSIG and DNSKEY as irrelevant; A and SOA didn't change)

```
            0   NSEC3PARAM 1 0 5 DEADBEEF
F66KKS17FM851AVA4EARFHS55I3TOO85.dnssectest.mvolfik.tk. 3600 IN NSEC3 1 0 5 DEADBEEF (
                    D60TA5J5RS4JD5AQK25B1BCUAHGP4DHC
                    A SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM )
D60TA5J5RS4JD5AQK25B1BCUAHGP4DHC.dnssectest.mvolfik.tk. 3600 IN NSEC3 1 0 5 DEADBEEF (
                    F66KKS17FM851AVA4EARFHS55I3TOO85
                    A RRSIG )
```

Now that I know that the only domains in this zone are `s3c.dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.` and `dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.`, I assume that the following Python script would get me the same hashes as in the signe zone file above: (from pseudocode in [RFC 5155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5155#section-5))

```py
import hashlib
def ih(salt, x, k):
    if k == 0:
        return hashlib.sha1(x + salt).digest()
    return hashlib.sha1(ih(salt, x, k-1) + salt).digest()

print(ih(bytes.fromhex("deadbeef"), b"s3c.dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.", 5).hex())

print(ih(bytes.fromhex("deadbeef"), b"dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.", 5).hex())
```

However, I instead got `b58374998347ba833ab33f15332829a589a80d82` and `545e01397a776ee73aa0372aea015408cc384574`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I looked into `dnspython` source code, and found the [nsec3_hash](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/5449af5318d88bada34f661247f3bcb16f58f057/dns/dnssec.py#L506) function. Turns out that the name must be in wire format (means removing dots and instead prefixing labels a length byte - `\x03s3c\x10dnssectest\x07mvolfik\x02tk\x00` etc, null byte at the end). And the result is encoded with base32 (0-9A-V), not hex. Probably easier just to use the dnspython library, but here's the full (a bit naive) code:

```py
import hashlib, base64

b32_trans = str.maketrans(
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"
)


def ih(salt, x, k):
    if k == 0:
        return hashlib.sha1(x + salt).digest()
    return hashlib.sha1(ih(salt, x, k - 1) + salt).digest()


def nsec3(salt, name, k):
    if not name.endswith("."):
        name += "."
    labels = name.split(".")
    name_wire = b"".join(len(l).to_bytes(1, "big") + l.lower().encode() for l in labels)
    digest = ih(bytes.fromhex(salt), name_wire, k)
    return base64.b32encode(digest).decode().translate(b32_trans)

print(nsec3("deadbeef", "dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.", 5))
print(nsec3("deadbeef", "s3c.dnssectest.mvolfik.tk.", 5))
```

This gets the correct hashes seen in the NSEC3 records

Comment: Instead of `base64.b32encode(digest).decode().translate(...)` you can directly use `base64.b32hexencode()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b32hexencode

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @AntoineCatton - that method is new in Python 3.10, which is quite recent, so I'll keep my answer like this for now

Comment: Seems you have a small typo there: `\x03s3c\x10dnssectest\x07mvolfik\x02tk\x00` should be `\x03s3c\x0adnssectest\x07mvolfik\x02tk\x00` instead, because the length of the "`dnssectest`" label, the decimal number `10` is `A` hexadecimal (not `10`), escaped as `\x0a` (not as `\x10`).